# How long has the Danger Room been sentient?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I am currently trying to catch up on X-Men stories I may have missed the first time around, and have just found out that the Danger Room actually became sentient, convincing a student to kill himself and turns a old, broken Sentinel loose on all psychics in the mansion. I'm pretty sure this took place in Joss Whedon's Astonishing series, but I was wondering if this was the first time this happened, or if it was based on an earlier storyline.

Comment: Since 2005 when Joss thought it up ;)

Answer (score 3):

#### The Danger Room's sentient existence was never hinted at before her first real appearance in Joss Whedon and John Cassaday in Astonishing X-Men Vol. 3 #9, March 2005.

- Though its sentience is retroactively tagged back to a rebuild of the Danger Room by the mutant Forge using Shiar technology, no stories were written about **[Danger's](http://marvel.wikia.com/Danger_%28Earth-616%29)** sentience before Whedon's run.

[image]

> - After Colossus had destroyed the original Danger Room, Professor Xavier, who had an extended sojourn in space with the Starjammers, returned to Earth and both the original and third teams of X-Men reassembled under his leadership.
> - At this time, Prof. Xavier asked **[Forge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forge_%28comics%29)**, a mutant with an unusual talent for inventing mechanical devices, to upgrade the Danger Room and include Shi'ar hard-light holographic technology.

[image]

Comment: what issue did the Shiar upgrade occur in? I'm trying to find it.